# CSS unusual use of :after

Tags: css, wordpress

I have come across a fragment of CSS that works. I would like to understand why it works for my own edification. My question is a general one on the sematics of using :after in CSS.

The Wordpress Twenty Nineteen theme puts a dark filter on feature images in order to make the (white) header text more readable.
I was searching for a way to remove the dark filter on specific feature images.
I found a [post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/featured-image-filter/) that suggests this css:

```
.site-header.featured-image:after {
   background: none;
}
```

It works a treat!

Using Firefox inspector I see that .site-header & .featured-image are both classes of an enclosing `<header>` element. Layout is flex.

I'm trying to get my head round this usage of :after. My search of :after suggests that is a way of adding 'content' after an element. This example add no content.. instead it seems to be modifying/overriding an existing property.

If I remove ':after' it stops working, so It's definitely necessary.

Can any kind expert explain what is going on here and/or point me to a spec that explains it?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour).

Comment: My question is of a more general nature. I don't have a live site that demonstrates the issue I can point to at this time. I've edited the question, hopefully to make my question clearer.

Comment: You can use code snippets services like CodePen, even StackOverflow allows to insert code snippets that run. But, for the sake of clarity and understand what you're trying to achieve, the best is to provide the attempt you did and what is the expected result. Otherwise, you might get downvotes to your question.

Comment: The `::after` pseudo element most certainly creates a `block` type container that covers the mentioned image. It's not really 'content', but simply a rectangle with a transparent background color.
In order for us to work with more a good guess, you should inspect that using firefox, the pseudo elements `::before` and `::after` are visible in the element tree. Show us what you see there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it actually appear to be seeing is [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

What `:after` does is add an element after the last child or content of the element that `:after` is applied to. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Here is a rough example

```css
.featured-image {
  position:relative;
  padding:5px;
 
}

.featured-image > p {
  position: relative;
  z-index:10;
}

.featured-image:after {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #CCC;
  z-index:1;
}

.site-header.featured-image:after {
   background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-image"><p> :after will have a background</p></div>
<div class="site-header featured-image"><p> :after wont't have a background 2</p></div>
```

As `.site-header.featured-image:after` is more specific than `.featured-image:after`, `.site-header.featured-image:after` takes preference for any conflicting styles.

Comment: Thank you. That's a great example to explain what I'm seeing and to illustrate the specificity rule... and the way you modify an already existing pseudo-element. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

With `::after` and `::before` you can add html elements or at least something that mimics the functionality of an html element.

`::before` will be placed before all the elements inside the element and `::after` would be the last element.

As an example, Say we already have this markup,

```
<div class="some-div">
  <h1>some text</h1>
  <div>Another div</div>
  <!-- bunch of other elements -->
</div>
```

If we add the following css,

```
.some-div::after,
.some-div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

It'll result in this markup,

```
<div class="some-div">
  ::before
  <h1>some text</h1>
  <div>Another div</div>
  <!-- bunch of other elements -->
  ::after
</div>
```

Now, I'm guessing that your Wordpress theme adds an after element with a `background-color` of some value that overlays the image. And by setting the background of that `::after` element to `none` you overwrite those styles and get rid of the overlay.

This snippet further elaborates what happens in the theme.

```css
.some-div {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
}

.img {
  position: relative;
  background-color: orangered;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.some-div:hover .img::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-div">
  <div class="img"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: ah great.. thank you.. this is the piece i was missing.. Now I understand that the css in my example was modifying an _already existing_ pseudo-element.. and this also explains the `::before` and `::after` that I'm seeing in the browser code-inspector